# Header inclusion not required for a .c program but for a .cpp program

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

I have seen that a .c program executed fine without including the header file though it throws an warning, however for a .cpp extension the non-inclusion of header file throws an error. Can some one explain the inside behavior?

Comment: Yes, C and C++ are different languages. (with different rules)

Comment: maybe, you are trying to access a member of the `std` namespace in C++. You probably didn't include the proper header and therefore, you are getting an error like: `"foo" is not a member of 'std'`.

Comment: You should consider warnings resulting from missing header files as errors.

Comment: In fact, using a function without a prototype is invalid C as well, but prior to C99, it **was** ok, so compilers behave backwards-compatible.

Comment: Re-reading the question, I don't think it deserves this many downvotes. Yes, you can read it as "I expect C and C++ to be the same", which is silly. But given the described code is indeed an error in both languages, it might be of interest for some why many C compilers accept it.

Comment: You could configure your compiler to treat warnings as errors. Then it will not run in C also. ;)

Comment: I wonder how this question was judged :) I wanted to know the inside behaviour of the c compiler that it doesn't require a preprocessor directive, however I have been shown lights for difference between c and c++. How funny... :)

Comment: @user3345621 asking why something is different between C and C++ is very likely to attract downvotes because many people here are fed up with questions somehow assuming they were the same language. A much better question would have been why the C compiler doesn't reject the code although it's wrong...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple answer: C and C++ are different languages with different rules.

For your concrete issue: Using a function without a prototype is indeed *illegal* in **both** languages. But in C, there was a time when this was legal (prior to C99), therefore many compilers still allow it with a warning for backwards-compatibility in their default modes of operation. On the other hand, this was *never* legal in C++, so it's unlikely to find a C++ compiler accepting such code at all.

Comment: Okay , but adding a -std=c99 to gcc also does the same, an warning and then proper execution. Yes you said it right, but a very interesting behavior...